# Como chamar uma JLabel com o seu conteúdo de uma outra Classe?

Tags: swing, java-8, jlabel

Em uma determinada classe eu tenh uma **JLabel** assim:

```
public class Links {

private JLabel link;

    lblLink.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                                        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    
                                            BareBonesBrowserLaunch.openURL("Link");
    
                                        }
                                    });
    }
```

E várias outras **JLabel** também. Como chamar essas **JLabel** em outra Classe (Tipo em minha Classe principal)?

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser feito assim:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ColecaoLabels {

    private JLabel linkGoogle = new JLabel("www.google.com");
    private JLabel linkYoutube = new JLabel("www.youtube.com");
    private JLabel linkGithub = new JLabel("www.github.com");

    public JLabel getLinkGoogle() {
        return linkGoogle;
    }

    public JLabel getLinkYoutube() {
        return linkYoutube;
    }

    public JLabel getLinkGithub() {
        return linkGithub;
    }
}
```

E sua classe principal:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ColecaoLabels colecao = new ColecaoLabels();

        JLabel google = colecao.getLinkGoogle();
        JLabel youtube = colecao.getLinkYoutube();
        JLabel github = colecao.getLinkGithub();
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Adriano Siqueira.